# Web Application audit trail

Tags: java, oracle

I am performing audit trail for a web application of the user id login who perform insert/update/delete of records.

There are no issues for insert / update triggers. However, for delete trigger the database would not know the "user id" who perform the delete.

I am using oracle database and jdbc with connection pooling.

How do I pass the "user id" to the delete trigger?

Comment: This might be helpful  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880729/how-to-send-arbitrary-parameters-to-oracle-trigger

Comment: but I am using connection pooling. There is no guarantee that the same connection will be return into the pool and used by another user id.

Comment: Clear of session id have to be done before connection is return to pool. http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dbms_session.php

Comment: Why would the database not know the UID of the user performing the delete?

Comment: I am not capturing the database connection id. I am capturing of the application user account login id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Audit4j](http://audit4j.org). It supports out of the box support for application auditing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using JPA? If so, are you using EclipseLink? If so, can this be done without triggers?

If you answered yes to all three answers, have I got an answer for you. Take a look at [EclipseLink's History table feature](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/History#Example_history_table) . I've used this in the past successfully to implement an audit trail.

Otherwise, consider "soft deletes" by having a Status column. Instead of physically removing the row from the database, you simple set the row status to disabled. In your Select queries, just add "and where status != disabled."