# Parameterized trigger - concurrency concerns

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle11g

My question is quite similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880729/how-to-send-arbitrary-parameters-to-oracle-trigger) but I need more guidance. I also read the [Oracle context](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/app_context.htm#DBSEG011) doc.

The current (test) trigger is :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHASSIS_DT_EVNT_AIUR_TRG_OLD AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE
OF ETA
ON CHASSITRANSPORTS
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO TS_CHASSIS_DATE_EVENTS (CHASSISNUMBER,DATETYPE,TRANSPORTLEGSORTORDER,OLDDATE,CREATEDBY,CREATEDDATE,UPDATEDBY,UPDATEDDATE) VALUES (:old.chassino,'ETA',:old.sortorder,:old.eta,'xyz',sysdate,'xyz',sysdate);

   EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
        NULL;
END TS_CHASSIS_DT_EVNT_AIUR_TRG;
```

Now the 'CREATEDBY', 'UPDATEDBY' will be the web application users who have logged in and made the changes which caused the trigger execution, hence, these values need to be passed from the application.

The web application :

1. Is deployed in Websphere Application Server where the datasources are configured
2. As expected, is using db connection pooling

My question is which approach mentioned in the thread and the doc. should I take to avoid the 'concurrency' issues i.e the updates by the app. users in multiple sessions at the application level as well the db level should not interfere with each other.

Comment: You probably have to "hack" Hibernate somehow, force some kind of callback to be executed each time a new transaction is started, or each time a connection is withdrawn from a pool. I doubt this is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any one of the approaches in that link would apply to you, primarily due to multi-user environment and connection pooling.

Connection pooling by nature allows different connections to share the same session. Setting a context (either sys_context or any other application context) is valid throughout the lifetime of the session. So two different connections can overwrite each other's values and read other's values. (concurrency issues)

I'd actually argue against doing an insert like this inside a trigger at all. It seems to me the insert you are doing is to write to a log table all updates that happened on the main table. If that is the case, why not insert to the log table at the time of making any updates to this table.

So the procedure that does `UPDATE CHASSITRANSPORTS ...` would also have another `INSERT` statement inside it that writes to the other table. If there is no procedure and it is a direct update statement from the application, then write a procedure for this.

You could say that there are multiple places where the same update happens and I'll suggest that in that scenario create an API for the base table `CHASSITRANSPORTS` that handles updates and so behind a black box also writes to the log table. Any place where you need to update that table column you'd use that API.

(I'm ignoring the fact that you are suppressing all errors in the trigger with `WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL` with the hope that this is probably just a small example)

Comment: I'm a bit confused  'Connection pooling by nature allows different connections to share the same session' or is it that multiple sessions can share one conn. Anyways, will two different web app. sessions overwrite each other's values in case they are using the same db. conn. from the pool?

Comment: Multiple connections from the app share the same session in a pool. The main reason you do connection pooling is to reduce the time taken in opening and closing new sessions.

Comment: @KaliyugAntagonist yes, the context values are valid through the oracle session. Multiple connections from the app might have connected to that same session through that pool and accessed the context value of a previous session. It is pretty easy to test. Create a small application that just connects to the database and print the session ID using `SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID') FROM DUAL`. You should see that connections share the same session that are in the same pool.

Comment: The updates to the table are happening at several flows in the code and I think trigger is a valid approach to track the updates to a table but I'm not sure what can be done in the web app. scenario. Any sugg. ?